# Keystone configuration

Tags: openstack, keystone

For several days I've been struggling with configuring keystone. When I try to create a tenant for an administrative user and a tenant for other OpenStack services:

```
 $ keystone tenant-create --name=admin --description="Admin Tenant"
 $ keystone tenant-create --name=service --description="Service Tenant"
```

I get the following:

```
Unable to establish connection to http://controller:35357/v2.0/tenants
```

Comment: What is the keystone URL you are using to configure keystone?

Comment: I just replaced a part of the url with "controller" when posting. The URL I have used are http://192.168.27.100:35357/v2.0, http://192.168.27.100:5000/v2.0, http://10.20.0.2:5000/v2.0/, http://10.20.0.2:35357/v2.0/ and the address to access the cloud controller. Nothing seems to work, I get the same result every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors like this usually mean that services registered in keystone used a hostname which may not be known to the client. Since you are clearly connecting to the keystone server, you can add a mapping in your hosts file, mapping the name 'controller' to the keystone server's Address.

The error indicates a straightforward connection error. Can you successfully resolve the address of 'Controller'? Can you ping 'controller'? Can you establish a TCP connection to 'controller' on port 35357?

The answer to the last question should be No. There may be a firewall blocking the connection to the remote machine. Disable any firewalls on your client machine and check for a network firewall.

Comment: I disabled the firewall, still having the same problem

Comment: Check if keystone is working correctly at all. Do this with the command "keystone token-get"

Comment: WARNING: Bypassing authentication using a token & endpoint (authentication credentials are being ignored).
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_service_catalog'